# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in Express, VueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, vue-router

i'm building a fullstack app with Express, VueJS and mongoose and it's basically a news feed app. Before two days i had another error but you guys helped me fix it but now i have another one and basically its kinda the same. I have my backend which is handling all the HTTP request and i'm rendering the data (the posts in this case) in the frontend. My main page loads all the posts successfully but i have another page called economy which shows only the posts which are in the economy category but when i try to render the data the same way i did for all the posts it says 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'.

I will provide you with the code so you don't get confused

ekonomi.js class:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Post = require("../../models/post");

router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.find()
    .where("category")
    .equals("5e0295317e7b5c07d8f359a4")
    .select("_id name content category")
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
      console.log(doc);
      res.status(200).json({
        count: doc.length,
        ekonomiPosts: doc
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

EkonomiService.js class which is in the frontend and has the getEconomyPosts() method :

```
const url = "http://localhost:9000/ekonomi/";

class EkonomiService {
  static getEconomyPosts() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        const data = res.data;
        resolve(
          data.posts.map(post => ({
            ...post
          }))
        );
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
}

export default EkonomiService;
```

EkonomiComponent.vue class

```
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="introTitle">Ekonomi</h1>
    <hr />
    <p class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
    <div class="posts-container">
      <div
        class="post"
        v-for="(post, index) in posts"
        v-bind:item="post"
        v-bind:index="index"
        v-bind:key="post._id"
      >
        <img :src="post.postImage" class="postImage" />
        <p class="category">{{ post.category.name }}</p>
        <p class="title">{{ post.name }}</p>
        <p class="content">{{ post.content }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EkonomiService from "../services/EkonomiService";

export default {
  name: "EkonomiComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      error: "",
      text: ""
    };
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.posts = await EkonomiService.getEconomyPosts();
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  }
};
```

When i try and fetch the data from the url http://localhost:9000/posts/ just like i did in my main page which returns all the posts it doesn't throw any errors, so i don't exactly know where the problem is.

[image: The data from backend]

I would appreciate if you could help me, thanks.

Comment: You only use map in one place. I'm guessing the remote API you're querying with axios isn't returning data in the format you're expecting. Check to see if `res.data` is `undefined` (in `EkonomiService.js`)

Comment: perhaps data has no property called `posts`

Comment: @DanPantry - `res.data` can't be undefined, since `data.posts.map` complains about `map` not `posts`

Comment: Apologies, you're right. I misread :)

Comment: @DanPantry the data is succesfully getting returned, because i can see it in my logs on cmd.

Comment: @kodak - show us (**in the question**) an example of the response you get from the request

Comment: @JaromandaX i added a picture to show you guys, but here i'll paste it here too :

``` [ { _id: 5e03cf30a42ac53ca04193b5,
    name: 'Biznesi më profitabil?',
    content: 'Klikoni për më shumë...',
    category: 5e0295317e7b5c07d8f359a4 },
  { _id: 5e03dfb8942efe25d4b1e448,
    name: 'test',
    content: 'testest',
    category: 5e0295317e7b5c07d8f359a4 } ]
GET /ekonomi/ 304 83.485 ms - -```

Comment: based on the **picture** you posted (why a picture?) ... you just want `data.map` -

Comment: @kodak - I said **in the question** - why not post it **in the question**

Comment: @JaromandaX when i do ```data.map``` i get the data.map is not a function, i posted the picture so you can see it better.

Comment: yes, and the data you posted has no array called `posts`, but seems to be an array itself, so `data.map` SHOULD exist - if what you posted is what you get

Comment: Perhaps you should post what the browser receives, rather than some random console.log from the server which could be anything?

Comment: @JaromandaX never mind bro i fixed it thanks a lot. I had the API return a new array called ekonomiPosts so i forgot to change the anme of it. Thanks a lot again

Comment: yes, I just spotted that in your backend code - so clearly you showed the wrong "result" :p - by the way, your frontend code still uses a Promise constructor anti-pattern by the way - and is FAR more complex than it needs to be :p .... `class EkonomiService {
    static getEconomyPosts() {
        return axios.get(url).then(res => res.data.ekonomiPosts)
    }
}` does what you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204851/discussion-between-kodak-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0):

Check your `EkonomiService.js` class. Try this code:

```js
result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then((result) => {
      const res = result.data.map((product) => {
        return {...product};
      })
      resolve(res);
    }).catch((error) => {
      if(typeof(error) == 'object'){
        alert(error)
      }
      reject(error.data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).